# Wrap all members of an array to pi in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I'm trying to wrap all members of a 2D array to pi, however whenever I tell it to print, I get [nan, nan].

Here's my wrap to pi function:

```
def wraptopi(x):
    pi = np.pi
    x = x - np.floor(x/(2*pi)) *2 *pi
    x[x >= pi] -= 2*pi
```

Here's me trying to fill the arrays with the new numbers:

```
y[0] = wraptopi(y[0]) 
y[1] = wraptopi(y[1])
```

So instead of x in my def wraptopi, should I instead write in a function?

Comment: Well, I'm not quite sure I understand Your question, but first of all `wraptopi` function is not returning anything so assigning `y[0] = wraptopi(y[0])` won't work...

Comment: Can you give some example input and output? I'm not sure what your wrapping operation is supposed to do. I'm assuming its not just `x % (2*pi)`?

Comment: @Tony Thanks! That was such a simple fix but I completely missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't want the function to mutate. Here is how you should change things:

```
def wraptopi(x):
        pi = np.pi
        x = x - np.floor(x/(2*pi)) *2 *pi
        return x[x >= pi] - 2*pi

y[0] = wraptopi(y[0]) 
y[1] = wraptopi(y[1])
```